# how can i check color profile (CMYK or RGB) in PDF file using itext library

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm working on an e-learning project. I have the pdf file's and I have to do the validation, that is pdf file contain the RGB/CMYK color profile or not.

If color profile is found RGB that is require to reject the file. I have tried so much but did not get appropriate logic/answer.

If anyone has any idea that how can i do this in itext or other java pdf library. please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

iText is for producing PDF files programmatically (e.g. converting from HTML to PDF, or producing PDF reports.) - it is only for producing, not for rendering, so you can't use it to check color.

In order to check color of a pixel in the PDF document
you need to render it to a BufferedImage or so, and then take the color of pixel in specific (x,y) position.

To render PDF you could use a library like ICEpdf, jpedal.

There is a topic on SO about java pdf renderer libraries [Java PDF Renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983730/java-pdf-renderer)